# Filtering data using EntityDataSource (dropdownlist)

Tags: asp.net, entitydatasource

I have a drop down list that is using entitydatasource, the user select a value form drop down list and the Grid View change based on the Order Status (Drowpdownlist). Below is the grid view DataSource. It works but when I go to page 4 for example and then shows a different value from dropdown list the grid view disappears. Please help.

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="GridViewEDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ServiceEntities" DefaultContainerName="ServiceEntities"
         EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Orders" Where="it.[OrderStatus] == @OrderStatus">
       <WhereParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="OrderStatus" ControlID="OrderStatusDropDownList" DbType="String" DefaultValue="Null"/>
       </WhereParameters>
```

Comment: When you choose a different value from the DropDownList, does that result set contain enough data to fill four pages? Can you change the the GridView's page back to 1 and see data?

Comment: Yes and Yes, the problem is when I'm on page 4 for example if I changed the dropdownlist the gridview disappears. When I go to page 1 and change the drop down list the gridview works fine. Its only happening when I'm on the gridview pages 2,3,4... Thank you for looking into this

Comment: So whenever you make a new selection in your DropDownList, can you have that process reset the current page to page 1? Does disappear mean it is no longer visible or there is no data?

Comment: BubbleHearth Thank you so much for your help. I added mygridView.PageIndex = 0 to the drop down list and everything works great!!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clearing some things up in the comments, a solution to this would be to set the current page on the GridView back to the first page when a new selection is made in the DropDownList. One reason for this would be because a secondary result set doesn't contain enough records to fill more than one page, therefore displaying nothing.

```
gridView.PageIndex = 0;
```